# getNodeSet by attribute values

Tags: r, xml-parsing, attributes

I'm parsing xml with R's getNodeSet function by attribute value with the following code:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "/body//*[@attribution='HM'][@*='checkmark'][@*='underline']")
```

The code above returns node content that includes all three of the above values (effectively, 'HM' And 'checkmark' And 'underline').

I'd like the function to return nodes in which the first value remains constant, but for which additional values are EITHER/OR (effectively, 'HM' AND 'checkmark' OR 'underline').

Grateful for any help.

Comment: Could you provide current/desired output samples?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to combine the type attribute values to be OR'd within a single set of square brackets, and supply 'or' without quotes:

```
getNodeSet(doc, "/body//*[@attribution='HM'][@*='underline' or @*='checkmark']")
```